# Min and Max date using Momentjs for Ionic datetime picker

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, ionic3

Can you tell me how to set `min` and `max` date of ionic [**datetime**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#datetime) picker using [**momentjs**](http://momentjs.com/docs/) (I have installed it properly)?

I have done it for the `min` date as shown below. But I need to do it using `momentjs`.

> min = current year
>
> max = curent year + 3 years

*.ts*

```
minDate = new Date().toISOString();
```

*.html*

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="D MMM, YYYY" [min]="minDate" 
formControlName="completionDate" [(ngModel)]="data.completionDate"></ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two dates using `moment` (it returns a current date/time when called without parameters). Add three years for the `maxDate`. Convert dates to the string in year format: `2017` and `2020`:

ts:

```
minDate = moment().format('YYYY');
maxDate = moment().add(3, 'y').format('YYYY');
// To set current date as today
myDate = moment().toDate();
```

view:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="D MMM, YYYY" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [(ngModel)]="myDate">
```

Comment: It is working fine. Thanks. But do you know how to set the start date as a current date? In other words, date selection should start from the current year. But now it shows `2020`.Any clue? See this: https://i.imgur.com/XLN69mF.png

Comment: Use `myDate = moment().toDate`, it will set `myDate` to the current date.

Comment: Actually, it is not working. You gave me the solution for my original question. I'll ask a separate question about that with working stackblitz project. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It should work, did you use brackets for `toDate` function? `myDate = moment.toDate()`.

Comment: Can you see this not working sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302766/date-selection-should-start-from-the-current-date

Comment: Found the issue, Ionic uses dates in _ISO 8601 Datetime Format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ_, not `Date` object. So the correct solution is `myDate = moment().format();` <= returns a string.

Comment: But it sets the default date no? I need to show that date only on the picker. I cannot change the `model` value. Any clue?