# Date selection should start from the current date

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, ionic3

Can you tell me how to start the date from the current date when the user tries to select the [**date from picker**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)? I don't need to set the default date. Because this field is not a mandatory field. So can you tell me how to do that?

Here you can see the [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4k9hmu) project. Please see the `home` folder.

*.ts*

```
 minDate = moment().format('YYYY');
 maxDate = moment().add(3, 'y').format('YYYY');
 completionDate: string;
```

*.html*

```
 <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>Completion Date</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="D MMM, YYYY" [min]="minDate" 
                  [max]="maxDate" [(ngModel)]="completionDate"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

*UI*

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that is stubbornly impossible...

Comment: Hmm.. There is no out of the box feature like that on the control yet. You can see it here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9846 @Vega

Comment: Yes, I saw that, too. And too bad they didn't change, it seems very useful and logical feature. I tried to set the ngModel value temporary while opening, but that didn't work either.:(

Comment: Yep, Hope they'll give this feature in the future @Vega